# SQL Server 2008 - query taking forever to run on with multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I am having an issue trying to run a query in my database. It is a relatively simple query but involving multiple tables (10), large number of rows (~60k+), and many columns (~200+).

When I try to execute the query it runs seemingly forever (2hrs+) and the database size balloons up to 60gb from a original 5gb before I kill the process.  I've set up a primary key on each table hoping that will speed up the process but its no different.

The weird issue is though I have tried running a similar query on another database with the same structure with but this time with 11 tables and I had the results came executed within 10 minutes.

Any suggestions on what I should be checking on would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Sample code

```
SELECT 
    A.DBUID, A.DAUID, A.CSDUID, A.CSDNAME,
    A.CDUID, A.CDNAME, A.PRUID,
    --W1
    A.[COM1-W1-LC] + B.[COM2-W1-LC] + C.[COM3-W1-LC] + D.[COM4-W1-LC] + 
      E.[COM5-W1-LC] + F.[COM6-W1-LC] + G.[COM7-W1-LC] + H.[COM8-W1-LC] + 
      I.[COM9-W1-LC] + J.[COM10-W1-LC] AS 'W1-LC',
    A.[COM1-W1-LS] + B.[COM2-W1-LS] + C.[COM3-W1-LS] + D.[COM4-W1-LS] +  
      E.[COM5-W1-LS] + F.[COM6-W1-LS] + G.[COM7-W1-LS] + H.[COM8-W1-LS] + 
      I.[COM9-W1-LS] + J.[COM10-W1-LS] AS 'W1-LS',
    A.[COM1-W1-PC] + B.[COM2-W1-PC] + C.[COM3-W1-PC] + D.[COM4-W1-PC] + 
      E.[COM5-W1-PC] + F.[COM6-W1-PC] + G.[COM7-W1-PC] + H.[COM8-W1-PC] + 
      I.[COM9-W1-PC] + J.[COM10-W1-PC] AS 'W1-PC',
    A.[COM1-W1-MC] + B.[COM2-W1-MC] + C.[COM3-W1-MC] + D.[COM4-W1-MC] +  
      E.[COM5-W1-MC] + F.[COM6-W1-MC] + G.[COM7-W1-MC] + H.[COM8-W1-MC] + 
      I.[COM9-W1-MC] + J.[COM10-W1-MC] AS 'W1-MC',
    A.[COM1-W1-MS] + B.[COM2-W1-MS] + C.[COM3-W1-MS] + D.[COM4-W1-MS] + 
      E.[COM5-W1-MS] + F.[COM6-W1-MS] + G.[COM7-W1-MS] + H.[COM8-W1-MS] + 
      I.[COM9-W1-MS] + J.[COM10-W1-MS] AS 'W1-MS',
    A.[COM1-W1-HC] + B.[COM2-W1-HC] + C.[COM3-W1-HC] + D.[COM4-W1-HC] + 
      E.[COM5-W1-HC] + F.[COM6-W1-HC] + G.[COM7-W1-HC] + H.[COM8-W1-HC] + 
      I.[COM9-W1-HC] + J.[COM10-W1-HC] AS 'W1-HC',
    A.[COM1-W1-HS] + B.[COM2-W1-HS] + C.[COM3-W1-HS] + D.[COM4-W1-HS] + 
      E.[COM5-W1-HS] + F.[COM6-W1-HS] + G.[COM7-W1-HS] + H.[COM8-W1-HS] + 
      I.[COM9-W1-HS] + J.[COM10-W1-HS] AS 'W1-HS',

    -- this continues on for ~200 sets
INTO 
    COM_Results
FROM 
    SeismicDesign_COM1 A
INNER JOIN 
    SeismicDesign_COM2 B ON A.DAUID = B.DAUID
INNER JOIN 
    SeismicDesign_COM3 C ON A.DAUID = C.DAUID
INNER JOIN 
    SeismicDesign_COM4 D ON A.DAUID = D.DAUID
INNER JOIN 
    SeismicDesign_COM5 E ON A.DAUID = E.DAUID
INNER JOIN 
    SeismicDesign_COM6 F ON A.DAUID = F.DAUID
INNER JOIN 
    SeismicDesign_COM7 G ON A.DAUID = G.DAUID
INNER JOIN 
    SeismicDesign_COM8 H ON A.DAUID = H.DAUID
INNER JOIN 
    SeismicDesign_COM9 I ON A.DAUID = I.DAUID
INNER JOIN 
    SeismicDesign_COM10 J ON A.DAUID = J.DAUID
```

Comment: does each table have an index on DAUID? with DAUID being the first element if a multi part index?  also show your execution plan (or at least look at it  the botteneck in the process should be easily visible as it will have the largest %.  A variety of problems could exist but by looking at the execution plan we can determine where the biggest bottleneck is and spend the time accordingly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan

Comment: Check to see if there is another process running that is blocking this.

Comment: You can select your answer as correct. Also, an index that satisfies the query is called a covering index, and is definitely cheaper for the optimizer to look through it then your huge, wide rows. Since 200 columns sits on a given page or two, a scan would require lots of reading as one row would quickly absorb a page in your extents, leading to lots of logical/physical reads. Lastly, how the heck do you have a table design where there are more than 200 columns? Is this really normalized properly?

Answer (score 2):

I am a noob.  After reading up on how execution plans work I started back tracking my code down to a single line and just joining 2 tables.  That resulted in a result of over 200k rows right there which was wrong.  Thats when I realized I had joined the tables on DAUID instead of DBUID.  DAUID is the next level up used to aggregation.

I am embarrassed on such a simple mistake.  Lesson learned!  Thanks for everyone whom offered their suggestions!

Comment: Your embarrasing question (as you put it) can be removed by deleting it.